# install mvc 4 on server without visual studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm getting a build server up and running (Windows Server 2008 R2).

The app will be MVC 4.

Do I need to install MVC3 and MVC4 onto the box? Or just MVC4?

I don't want to install a whole bunch of Visual Studio kerfuffle on the build server though. Which the web platform installers seem to be all wrapt up in.

Cheers for any MVC 4 wisdom!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application is going to use MVC 4 then all you need to install is ASP.NET MVC 4. You don't need to install Visual Studio. The MVC installer checks if VS is installed and if it is it adds the project templates to VS 2010. Otherwise it deploys only the runtime assemblies into the GAC.

Comment: thanks Darin you rock! if only you wrote documentation for Microsoft!

Comment: I'm trying to install MVC 4 on a server right now and it's failing because the Visual Studio service pack install is failing (presumably because VS isn't on the server). The [standalone installer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683) also fails, telling me "This product requires VWD 2010 SP1". I think I'm just gonna see about putting the damn DLL into Git, personally.